# Android studio sign up not working

Tags: java, php, android, performance

I am creating a social network for android with android studio . When I enter text in all of the fields and click `Register` nothing happens . I previously checked the Android Monitor and it printed that I wasn't using the Internet permission . So I added that in . Now I get no errors and still nothing happens when I click Register . When I click Register , if the registration was successful , the user's info goes into the database and then they go to the login screen . Can someone help me fix this problem ?

Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

registeractivity.java :

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPw);
    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    final TextView loginLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoginHere);

    loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(loginIntent);

        }
    });

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String pw = etPw.getText().toString();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            if (etUsername.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (etPw.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (etEmail.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "E-mail is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, pw, email, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

registerrequest.java :

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://hash.host22.com/register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String username, String pw, String email, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("pw", pw);
    params.put("email", email);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;

}
}
```

register.php :

```
 if(isset($_POST['bRegister'])) {

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
            echo"Fill in username to sign up";
                } else {

                if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
                 echo"Fill in password to sign up";
                } else {

                if (empty($_POST["pw2"])) {
                echo"Confirm password to sign up";
                 } else {

                if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                     echo"Fill in email to sign up";
                 } else {

                 if ($_POST['pw'] == $_POST['pw2']) {
                 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
                 $pw= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pw"]);
                 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);

         $result = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {
                    echo "Username exists";
                    } else {

                       $result2 = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email. "'");

                       if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
                       {
                       echo "Email exist";
                       } else {

                       $pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 14));          

               $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, pw, email) VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . $pw . "', '" . $email . "')";
                       if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){                                  
                       // if insert checked as successful echo username and password saved successfully
            echo"success";
                       }else{
                       echo mysqli_error($con);
                       }   

                    } } } else{
                              echo "The passwords do not match.";  // and send them back to registration page
            }}}}}
     }
```

please help thanks .

Comment: Hmm are those closing braces in register.php correct???

Comment: Where ? I didn't post all of my code by the way . Just the relevant stuff

Comment: Yes . I didn't post all my code . When I go on the register.php webpage I don't get errors

Answer (score 0):

I have a registration activity on my app that uses a similar pair of java files as yours (a registerActivity and a registerRequest), but for my php file I used something a bit more simple. I'll post it below, give it a go if you want or adapt your own code to suit it, but it works 100% of the time for me using a 000webhost db.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$response = array();
$response["success"] = 0;  

$email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE email = '$email'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($email_check)) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

$statementR = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO tableName (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statementR, "sss", $name, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statementR);


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE email = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $email, $password);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = 2;  
    $response["user_id"] = $user_id;    
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["email"] = $email;

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

The email_check method checks to see whether an email already exists, then returns a response with an integer value which the app then interprets.

There aren't any password/username checks in my php script since that's all done app-side since it prevents unnecessary database calls (I can post that code too if you'd like). You could probably add your server-side data checks to the code above if you want to.

The register.php file modified for you:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

$name = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pw = $_POST["pw"];

$response = array();
$response["success"] = 0;  

$email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($email_check)) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

$statementR = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, pw, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statementR, "sss", $username, $pw, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statementR);


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $username, $pw, $email);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = 2;  
    $response["username"] = $username;    
    $response["pw"] = $pw;
    $response["email"] = $email;

}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Also in your RegisterActivity, update the line `if(success){...}` to `if(success == 2){...}`.

For clarity, here's my RegisterActivity (very similar to yours):

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText registerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    final EditText registerEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    final EditText registerPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    final EditText registerConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPasswordConfirm);

    final Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    final TextView registerLogInLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerLogInLink);

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = registerName.getText().toString();
            final String email = registerEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = registerPassword.getText().toString();
            final String passwordCheck = registerConfirm.getText().toString();

            if(name.length() > 1 & email.length() > 5 & password.length() > 5 & password.equals(passwordCheck)) {

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        int success = jsonResponse.getInt("success");

                        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
                        System.out.println(success);

                        if (success == 2) {
                            Integer user_id = jsonResponse.getInt("user_id");
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String email = jsonResponse.getString("email");

                            UserCredentials.setUserLoggedInStatus(getApplicationContext(), true);
                            UserCredentials.setLoggedInUserEmail(getApplicationContext(), email);
                            UserCredentials.setLoggedInUserName(getApplicationContext(), name);
                            UserCredentials.setLoggedInUserID(getApplicationContext(), user_id);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        } else if (success == 1) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, email already registered.")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Try again", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, please try again")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Try again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            RegisterActivity.this.recreate();}})

                                    .create().show();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, email, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);

            } else if(name.length() > 1 & email.length() <= 5 & password.length() <=5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, email and password invalid. Passwords must be more than 5 characters.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else if(name.length() > 1 & email.length() <= 5 & password.length() > 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, email invalid.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else if(name.length() > 1 & email.length() > 5 & password.length() <= 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, invalid password. Passwords must be more than 5 characters.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else if(name.length() <= 1 & email.length() <= 5 & password.length() <=5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, all credentials invalid.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else if(name.length() <= 1 & email.length() <= 5 & password.length() > 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, name and email invalid.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else if(name.length() <= 1 & email.length() > 5 & password.length() <= 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, name and password invalid. Passwords must be more than 5 characters.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            }  else if(name.length() > 1 & email.length() > 5 & password.length() > 5 & !password.equals(passwordCheck)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Registration failed, passwords do not match.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                alertMessage.setMessage("Something went wrong, please try again.")
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    registerLogInLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent LogInIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LogInActivity.class);
            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(LogInIntent);

        }
});
```

You can ignore the alertDialogs unless you want custom alerts, in which case feel free to copy them. Also make sure your RegisterRequest file is connecting to the correct URL.